# Пожалуйста, проверьте правильно затранскрибировала ли текст?

Tags: транскрипция

Горит восток зарею новой Уж на равнине по холмам, Грохочут пушки, дым багровый Кругами всходит к небесам На встречу утренним лучам.
[г^р'Ит в^стОк з^рOjу нОвъj ушнър^вн'Ин'ь пъх^лмАм г^рхOчут пУшк'и д'Ым б^грОв'ыj кругАми фсхОд'ит кн'ьб'и(э)сАм нафстр'Эчу утр'ьн(долгая)'им лучАм]

Answer (score 1):

.. з^р'Ojу 
уш нър^вн'Ин'ь (уж-наречие,самостоятельное слово)
 гр^хOчут
  дЫм - зачем мягкость?
 б^грОвыj -нет мягкости у "в"
кругАм'и

И паузы надо расставить:/-запятая,конец строки,//-точка